# Keep table row colors alternating even as some rows get hidden from filtering

Tags: jquery, html-table

On the following page, I use the built-in HTML table functionality to display a table that automatically has alternating background row colors:

http://www.realitysharesadvisors.com/divcon/#table

However, if a user uses the colored buttons right above the table to, based on certain criteria, filter the information the table shows, then that causes some specific rows to become hidden, and so the remaining rows lose the automatic alternating row colors.

As I'm using the native HTML table functionality, do you have any suggestions on how to maintain the alternating row colors when filters are applied and rows then become hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Or, make use of jQuery (javascript) and these CSS parameters to arrive at desired result:

Add two new CSS classes:

```
<style type="text/css">
.TFtable tr.even {
    background: #dae5f4;
}
    .TFtable tr.odd {
    background: #b8d1f3;
}
</style>
```

And finally some jQuery scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    function updateRows() {
        $("table.TFtable tr:visible:odd").addClass("odd");
        $("table.TFtable tr:visible:even").addClass("even");
    }
</script>
```

Execute the function: updateRows(), each time you hide/show a row from this table.

Comment: Thank you Ren.  That still doesn't seem to be working.  I'm wondering if it's because the table is using the "tablesorter" class for that plugin, so I can't add my own css to it.

Comment: You're welcome @KianSalehizadeh . If the table is already using class called **tablesorter** that you cannot modify, try replacing all **TFtable** from my javascript and CSS with **tablesorter** and give it a second go. Just a thought. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

With pure css it is possible

Assume that filtered rows are added '.dn' class.

```
tbody>tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
tbody>tr:nth-child(odd of :not(.dn)){
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
} 

tbody>tr:nth-child(even of :not(.dn)) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .TFtable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
    .TFtable td{ 
        padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
    }
    /* provide some minimal visual accomodation for IE8 and below */
    .TFtable tr{
        background: #b8d1f3;
    }
    /*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
    .TFtable tr:nth-child(odd){ 
        background: #b8d1f3;
    }
    /*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
    .TFtable tr:nth-child(even){
        background: #dae5f4;
    }
</style>
<table class="TFtable">
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
</table>
```

you can achieve this via CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.